# How to pass data between two child components in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

So i want to pass data between two child component using React Context Api but it shows the following error
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `App`.
Here is my code

App.js

```
import React,{ MyProvider} from 'react'
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch,Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import Login from './Login';
import Home from './Home';
import UserInfo from "./UserInfo";
import SetInfo from './SetInfo';

export default class App extends React.Component{
  
   render (){

    return(
      
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route  path = "/" exact={true} component={Home}/>
          <Route  path = "/Login"   component = {Login}/>
          <Route  path = "/UserInfo" component = {UserInfo}/>
          <Route  path = "/SetInfo" component = {SetInfo}/>
        </Switch>
           <div>
            <MyProvider>
              <div className="App">
               <SetInfo/>
                <UserInfo/>
              </div>
               </MyProvider>
            </div>
      </Router>

        
      
    )
   }
  
}
```

MyProvider.js

```
import React,{Component} from 'react'

 export const MContext = React.createContext();  //exporting context object
   class MyProvider extends Component {
state = {message: ""}
render() {
        return (
            <MContext.Provider value={
            {   state: this.state,
                setMessage: (value) => this.setState({
                            message: value })}}>
            {this.props.children}   //this indicates that all the child tags with MyProvider as Parent can access the global store.
            </MContext.Provider>)
    }
}
export default MyProvider;
```

SetInfo.js

```
import React, {useState,MyProvider} from 'react';
import { Button} from 'semantic-ui-react'
import UserInfo from "./UserInfo";

import { MContext } from './MyProvider';
 

import './SetInfo.css'


function SetInfo(props){
    
   
    const [State, setState] = useState("");

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        setState(event.target.value);
    }

    const sendMessage = () =>{
        setState(State)
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <div className="dots"> 
              <span class="dot" id="dot1"></span>
              <span class="dot" id="dot2"></span>
              <span class="dot" id="dot3"></span>
            </div>
            <div className="title">
                <h1>{props.location.user}</h1>
            </div>
            <hr></hr>
            <h2>Modifier les informations de l'utilisateur</h2>
            <form class="ui form">
            <textarea placeholder="Tell us more" rows="2" onChange={handleChange}>
            </textarea></form>
            <div>
             <MContext.Consumer>
               {(context)=>(
                   <button onClick={()=>{context.sendMessage()}}>Send</button>
               )

               }  
             </MContext.Consumer>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    )
        
}
export default SetInfo;
```

Comment: In SetInfo.js component it is functional component consume context using useContext hook

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you are importing MyProvider from the react package itself.

`import React,{ MyProvider} from 'react'` in App.js.
Shouldn't it be imported from MyProvider.js file ?